# How to pass values to a new open（created） window (dialog, panel, page etc) with MVVM in Blazor

Tags: mvvm, blazor, parameter-passing, viewmodel

I have "PageMain" with "PageMainViewModel" binded, there is a "Edit" button in "PageMain", What is the best practice in MVVM for Blazor to pass the values(example:ProductInfo) to the new opened edit form window ("EditFormWindow") when the "Edit" button is clicked?

I used to use the massagers to communicate between each viewmodel, but in this case, the "EditFormWindow" is new opened, Even I added a register of messager in the constructor of "EditFormWindowViewModel", when sending message (passing data) from "PageMainViewModel", the "EditFormWindowViewModel" is not initialized yet so "EditFormWindowViewModel" cannot receive the message(passed data) from "EditFormWindow".

What I am doing now is to pass the values from View (Balzor file) to Viewmodel, but I am wondering if there is a better solution that I don't have to write any codes in View(Blazor file).

Comment: Are we talking Blazor or Razor?  This sounds like server side Razor.  Is the `View` a service?

Comment: It's a Blazor Server App, the "View" is the component (*.razor) which will be shown in a web page.